# Unique Session ID

Tags: powershell

I am try to figure out how to make Unique Session ID regardless if the whole script is run or only part of the script is run.  If part of the script is run it would in IDE environment. The Unique Session ID will be made in the logging function.  The Unique Session ID needs to only be generated once per run. I need this in PowerShell.

Comment: have you tried using Guids ? `[GUID]::NewGuid()`

Comment: Yes, GUID is a unique 128bit number.  The issue is knowing when a session started or ended if they only select 50 lines from the middle of the script.

Comment: I think the fundamental problem is that you have no control over what parts of a script the user runs, given that arbitrary text can be selected and submitted for execution - how would you guarantee that your logging function is involved? Please clarify your requirements.

Comment: I can guarantee that they will select the 'logging function'.  They have to use a function to do anything and there is logging in every function.  If you have a different way I will listen.

Comment: You can't guarantee that they won't skip the first 50 lines of your script, but you can guarantee that they won't skip the lines that call your logging function? How does that work?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a logging function wrapper, you could use start-transcript

```bsh
Start-Transcript `
   -Force `
   -IncludeInvocationHeader

$sessionId = [GUID]::NewGuid()
Write-Host ("Session [$sessionId] started")
```

Comment: I was not looking for a user account session.  The "sessionID" is per user.  I ran your script a few times and it gave me "1" every time.  I ran I was looking to make unique session ID for every time the script or part of the script is ran.

Comment: Updated to use GUID instead. You can use any random identifier you want.